# Application Insight: Not able to see server responses

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I configured application insight with my website and have added the instrumentation key as well as added the application pool to the performance counter (both default + application specific) and have even provided application pool security rights on "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile" but I am still not able to see any server responses in application insight.

Also i have created a Url Ping test in application insight and that is responding fine on each attempt

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to troubleshoot.

1. Using fiddler - check traffic going out to https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track
2. You can do from dev tools like

> Run your application in debug mode in Visual Studio (F5). Use the application so as to generate some telemetry. Check that you can see events logged in the Visual Studio output window.

More troubleshooting can be found here -
[Troubleshooting no data - Application Insights for .NET/.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-troubleshoot-no-data?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422)

Comment: The website is deployed on a client VM so i cant install fiddler or use dev tools there. I am able to configure application insight on a local VM but when i configure over here i dont receive any server responses

Comment: No need to install in VM, just try to access in web browser & inspect in fiddler locally in your laptop/desktop.

Comment: Do you know where the logs are kept for application insight?

Comment: Which logs? Are you the implementer? Did you get a chance to go thru the link I posted ?

Comment: Arun i did i am getting the following message 
"POST https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track 400 (Invalid instrumentation key)" but i have checked the instrumentation key is actually the same

Comment: Can you paste your config in original post with dummy key ?

Comment: Are you getting client side metrics using js ?

Comment: it was the intrumentation key that was wrong being sent from a different part of the code that was wrong thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you’d like to configure and show the performance counters, [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-performance-counters) explained how to configure and collect performance counters, please refer to it.

Please make sure you add specific performance counters correctly, the following is an example.

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
  <!--
  Use the following syntax here to collect additional performance counters:
  -->
  <DefaultCounters/>
  <Counters>
    <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Handle Count" ReportAs="Process handle count" />
  </Counters>
  <!--
  PerformanceCounter must be either \CategoryName(InstanceName)\CounterName or \CategoryName\CounterName

  NOTE: performance counters configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.

  The following placeholders are supported as InstanceName:
    ??APP_WIN32_PROC?? - instance name of the application process  for Win32 counters.
    ??APP_W3SVC_PROC?? - instance name of the application IIS worker process for IIS/ASP.NET counters.
    ??APP_CLR_PROC?? - instance name of the application CLR process for .NET counters.
  -->
</Add>
```

Search and display performance counter reports in Analytics:

[image]

Comment: Actually i am just looking to see server responses, I am not getting any of those.

Comment: The website is deployed on a client VM so i cant install fiddler or use dev tools there. I am able to configure application insight on a local VM but when i configure over here i dont receive any server responses